# Do I have to reload a module in python to capture changes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, python-import

I am running `python 3.6.4` (anaconda, spyder).

Do I need to reload a user-defined module in order to capture the changes?

For example, suppose I wrote the simple function and save it in `test.py` file:

```
def plus5(x):
    return x + 5
```

Then in the IPython console I type

```
import test as t
```

and then I change the user-defined function to:

```
def plus5(x):
    return x + 500
```

Then when I type in IPython console

```
t.plus5(0)
```

it returns 500 without re-importing or reloading the module first.

If I change the function name from `plus5` to something else then I have to re-import the module to see the change. But when I change the function statements then it automatically captures the changes without re-importing the module

From the Python documentation:

> **Note**: For efficiency reasons, each module is only imported once per interpreter session. Therefore, if you change your modules, you must restart the interpreter – or, if it’s just one module you want to test interactively, use `importlib.reload()`
>
> e.g. `import importlib; importlib.reload(modulename)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a feature in the IPython interpreter name [`autoreload`](http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config/extensions/autoreload.html). It has the magic command `%autoreload` which allows for activating or deactivating this feature. It seems to be on by default, but I was not able to find something proving that.

Answer (score 1):

As [Megalng](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8472976/megaing) explained, this is a built in feature of `IPython` interpreter and in default `Python` interpreter you have to use `importlib` to reload the module. Here is default python interpreter execution,

```
Python 3.6.2 (default, Sep  5 2017, 17:37:49) 
[GCC 4.6.4] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 
>>> 
>>> 
>>> import test as t
>>> t.plus5(0)
5
>>>   
>>> 
>>> #Changed function body to return x + 500    
... 
>>> t.plus5(0)
5
>>> import test as t
>>> t.plus5(0)   
5
>>> #It had no affect, even importing again doesn't work.
... 
>>> import importlib; importlib.reload(t)         
<module 'test' from '~/test.py'>
>>> 
>>> t.plus5(0)
500
>>> #Now it works !
... 
>>>
```

As you can see, even after changing function body to `return x + 500`, it still generated a result of **5** for `t.plus5(0)`, even importing test module again did not help. It only started working when importlib was used to reload test module.